# How can I optimize this String search/replace method?

Tags: java, string, search, optimization, replace

I am implementing my own web server. The following method searches for server side includes and builds the html page appropriately.

`public String getSSI(String content) throws IOException {`

```
    String beginString = "<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL=\"";
    String endString = "\"-->";

    int beginIndex = content.indexOf(beginString);
    while (beginIndex != -1) {
        int endIndex = content.indexOf(endString, beginIndex);
        String includePath = content.substring(beginIndex+beginString.length(), endIndex);

        File includeFile = new File(BASE_DIR+includePath);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) includeFile.length()];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(includeFile);    
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();

        String includeContent = new String(bytes);
        includeContent = getSSI(includeContent);

        content = content.replaceAll(beginString+includePath+endString, includeContent);

        beginIndex = content.indexOf(beginString);
    }

    return content;
}
```

I know StringBuilder is faster than String, but is that all I can do to optimize this? The original data is read into a byte array and converted into a String, at which point it is passed into this method, and the output is converted back into a byte array and sent to the client.

Comment: Any optimizations you make are probably going to be insignificant compared to disk IO. Have you profiled your code and found this method to be an actual bottleneck?

Comment: @Supericy No, but I would like to form good code writing habits.

Comment: Writing optimized code =/= good code writing habits. Writing readable, maintainable is much more important. Once a piece of code becomes an issue (determined from profiling your application), *then* would be a good time to go back and revise the problematic areas (and if the optimizations obfuscate the code a lot, make sure to heavily comment it!).

Comment: @Supericy Your advice is well received. I should probably learn how to use a profiler. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how significant of an impact this will have, but instead of reading into a byte array and and converting to a String, you can use the [IOUtils toString(InputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method to read directly to a String.  Likewise, you can [write the String directly to an OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#write%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: I will consider this. Thank you.